# AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment got stuck while creating

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Whenever I try to create an application, it gets created but when I try to create environment it got stuck on multiple places.
I have attached the error log file below. I have also tried multiple solutions. Like I have erased all the command from requirement.txt. I have also created a new application and new environment all over again but its still stuck at the same places.

[image: Full log]

My requirement.txt looks like this:

```
Django==2.1.5
django-filter==2.0.0
djangorestframework==3.9.0
Markdown==3.0.1
pytz==2018.7
django-timezone-field==3.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.3
django-allauth==0.39.1
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
psycopg2==2.7.7
django-bootstrap4==0.0.8
django-fontawesome-5==1.0.16
Pillow==6.0.0
boto3==1.10.28
django-storages==1.7.1
django-smtp-ssl
django-ses
stripe==2.36.2
django-background-tasks==1.2.0
zappa==0.48.2
django-s3-storage==0.12.5
celery==4.4.0
pycurl==7.43.0.4
```

And my django.config file is this:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: SB_Main/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 30
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    /static/: "static/"
container_commands:
  01_makeMigrations:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations SB_Auth"
    leader_only: true
  02_makeMigrations:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations SB_API"
    leader_only: true
  03_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  04_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
  05_makeMigrations:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py loaddata dummyData.json"
    leader_only: true
  06_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

It also gets stuck here and give this error:

[image]

Comment: Is there any useful information in the `/var/log/eb-activity.log` file? You can request the logs using the Elastic Beanstalk console.

Comment: @littleforest No useful information in the log file as well. All the requirements are successfully installed. I can show you the log file as well if you want. Any possible reason for this issue?

Comment: I'm not a Django person unfortunately, but I've run into this with Rails, and usually the log has more details about what went wrong. Hopefully someone else has some insight!

Comment: @littleforest Thanks for mentioning the log file. I have resolved the issue. It was issue with pycurl. It was not getting installed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the log file, I have identified it was issue with requirement.txt pycurl. It was not getting installed properly.